# Can this for loop be vectorized for speed

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I need to find out the difference of every element of H_A with every element in H_B, here is my approach

```
              H_A=reshape(H_A,1,[]);
              H_B=reshape(H_B,1,[]);
              for i=1:SIZE^2
              D(i,:)=((H_A(i)-H_B)).^2;
              end
```

can this be vectorized for speed.

Comment: The dupe is for 3D points, this question is for 1D points. But the answers over there actually work for any number of dimensions, including 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bsxfun.

```
H_A = reshape(H_A, [], 1);
H_B = reshape(H_B, 1, []);
D = bsxfun(@minus, H_A, H_B).^2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use broadcasting:

```
H_A = reshape(H_A, [], 1);
H_B = reshape(H_B, 1, []);
(H_A-H_B).^2;
```

Probably the fastest option. There is also `pdist2` which allows you to calculate different distance metrics:

```
H_A = reshape(H_A, [], 1);
H_B = reshape(H_B, [],1);
pdist2(H_A,H_B,'squaredeuclidean')
```